# c++ Mysql save binary blob in database

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

So I am using g++ and Mysqlcppconn (Mysql c++ connector) on a ubuntu 64 bit machine. I want to insert binary data blob into the database and be able to retrieve it. 
Retieval

```
typedef unsigned char byte;

byte data[512];
istream *buf=res->getBlob(1);
buf->read((char*)data,512);
```

I just hope this works I am not too sure though. Here res is a ResultSet.

For storing in database I am not able to figure out how do I convert my byte* to istream.

Thanx for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in using the stream buffer to write blob in database

```
struct membuf: std::streambuf
{
    membuf(char* b, char* e) { this->setg(b, b, e); }
};

byte *p = something....;
membuf buf((char*)p,(char*)p+ALPHABET_SIZE*sizeof(ull));
istream is(&buf);

ps->setBlob(1,&is);
```

here ps is a PreparedStatement.. :)